# DELETE 405 (Method Not Allowed) - Laravel with Axios

Tags: laravel, axios, crud, delete-row, http-status-code-405

Basically i am trying to delete a row using axios, but i keep getting `DELETE 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

This is my api route for delete:

```
Route::delete('/vehicles/{id}', [VehiclesController::class, 'destroy']);
```

In the controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    
    $vehicleDelete = Vehicle::findOrFail($id);
    $vehicleDelete->delete();

    return response()->json([
        "status" => true
    ], 200);

}
```

The button in the front-end:

```
<button class = 'btn btn-danger' onclick = "deleteBtn(${item.id})">Delete</button>
```

I tried using `console.log` to see if the i get the correct id and it does get the correct.

And here is the axios function:

```
const deleteBtn = (id) => {
        axios.delete("api/vehicles/" + id)
        .then(response => {
                console.log(id);
            })
    }
```

Comment: code looks good .try php artisan route:clear

Comment: @JohnLobo I did try it now, still the same

Comment: try adding `return false` in the end of your `deleteBtn` function

Comment: @apokryfos Didn't change anything

Comment: What is the full URL that this `DELETE` request is hitting? It might be the wrong URL, depending on the page you're sending the request from. You might need to do `axios.delete(\`/api/vehicles/${id}\`)` (i.e. include the leading `/`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out almost everything here is the solution that i randomly came with:

API Route:

```
Route::delete('/vehicles/{id}', [VehiclesController::class, 'destroy']);
```

Destroy method in the controller:

```
    public function destroy($id)
    {

    $vehicle = Vehicle::find($id);

    if(!$vehicle) {
        return response()->json(["error" => "Vehicle does not exist!!"]);
    }

    if($vehicle->delete()) {
        return response()->json(["success" => "Vehicle deleted!!"]);
    }

    return response()->json(["error" => "Something bad happened!!"]);

    }
```

front-end button:

```
<button class = 'btn btn-danger' onclick = "deleteBtn(${item.id})">Delete</button>
```

And finally, the javascript function:

```
const deleteBtn = (id) => {
        axios.delete(API.url + (API.routes.deleteVehicles.replace("{id}", id)))
        .then(response => {
            vehicleTable.innerHTML = "";
            drawVehicles();
        })
    }
```

For reference here is the API object:

```
const API = {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api',
        routes: {
            getVehicles: '/vehicles',
            deleteVehicles: '/vehicles/{id}',
            createVehicles: '/vehicles'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice solution! Just be careful with hardcoding `API.url`; that can change based on your `.env` file and `config/app.php`. A neat thing you can do is name your routes, like `Route::delete(...)->name('api.vehicles.delete')`, then use that URL as a data-attribute: `<button data-url="{{ route('api.vehicle.delete', ['id' => ':vehicleId']) }}" ...>`, then in your click handler: `axios.delete(button.data('url').replace(':vehicleId', 'id))`. That guarantees (unless tampered with) the URL is correct (uses your PHP config), and replaces `:vehicleId` with a valid integer from your `id` JS variable.